# JMSSerializer not serializing entity

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle, jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer

I am trying to get a serialized entity response using the JmsSerializerBUndle and the FOSRestBundle. unfortunatly i'm unable to do so because i'm having problems
with the response.. i'm not sure the system recognizes the file `Entity.SearchEngine.yml`

Any Ideas how I could find why its not working?

```
#src\example\CoreBundle\Resources\config\serializer\Entity.SearchEngine.yml
Example\CoreBundle\Entity\SearchEngine:
  exclusion_policy: ALL
  properties:
             id:
                 expose: true
                 groups: [search.list,search.details]
             has_product_flight:
                 expose: true
                 groups: [search.details]
             selfLink:
               expose: true
               groups: [self.link]
```

Rest action (using the FOSRestBundle):

```
    /**
     * GET /search/engines
     *
     * @return array
     * @Rest\View(serializerGroups={"search.details", "self.link"})
     */
    public function getSearchEnginesAction()
    {
        $searchEngineManager = $this->get('search_manager');
        return $searchEngineManager->getSearchEngineList();
    }
```

the response im getting is 
`{
0: { }
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, is SerializerBundle configured correctly? You should supply config for paths to your `.yml`s and corresponding namespaces, like this:

```
jms_serializer:
    metadata:
        auto_detection: true
        directories:
            ExampleCoreBundle:
                namespace_prefix: "Example\\CoreBundle"
                path: "@ExampleCoreBundle/Resources/config/serializer/"
```

Be sure to check that your `search.manager` service returns instances of `SearchEngine`. Also, I'm not sure if dots are supported in group names.